# callback function with underscore _.each()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to implement an _.each() (that I wrote) inside another function and I keep getting "undefined" returned to me. I'm trying to use _.each() to apply a test function to an array. I know this a simple callback syntax issue, but its perplexing me.

thanks in advance from a noob.

here's my function:

```
_.filter = function(collection, test) {
  _.each(collection, test());
};
```

this returns 'undefined'

this is the array i'm passing as 'collection':

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

this is the function i'm passing as 'test':

```
function (num) { return num % 2 !== 0; }
```

here's my _.each():

```
_.each = function(collection, iterator) {

    if( Object.prototype.toString.call( collection ) === '[object Array]' ) {
        for (var i=0; i<collection.length; i++){
            iterator(collection[i], i, collection);
        }
    } else if (typeof collection === 'object'){
        for (var i in collection){
            iterator(collection[i], i, collection)
        }
    } else if (typeof collection === 'int'){
        console.log('int')
    }
};
```

Comment: try _.each(collection, test); - you were calling the test function test()

Comment: Your `_.each` function doesn't have any `return` statements, so why do you expect it to return something?

Comment: the function i pass has a return statement, when i pass the test function without the () i get undefined.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't work like that. `return` returns from a function without doing anything to the function that called that function. Your `filter` implementation also has no `return` so it won't return anything either.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:underscorejs] if you've written the functions yourself?

Comment: @GruffBunny i get undefined from both test){ and test()){

Comment: @user3000326 my test function has a return statement

Comment: @muistooshort i changed my function to:  `_.filter = function(collection, test) {
      var result=[];
      console.log('test function' test);
      result.push(_.each(collection, test));
      console.log('result array ' + result);
      return result;
    };`                                                         the result array is [ undefined ]

Comment: @Bergi its tagged underscore because i'm working on an underscore tutorial that has us write a and implement helper functions

Comment: Your `each` implementation does return anything so `ary.push(_.each(...))` will always give you `[undefined]`. Have you looked at the Underscore source for pointers?

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for the help. my 'test' function has a 'return' in it: `function (num) { return num % 2 !== 0; }` does my _.each() need one too? i feel like this is a really simple scope or syntax issue.

Comment: `_.each` is a function, functions in JavaScript don't return anything unless they have an explicit `return whatever` statement in them. I'd recommend that you do a quick review of the Underscore source, it is fairly readable and will give you some examples that match what you're trying to do.

Comment: @muistooshort I used my _.each() function in another function with out a return and it works:  `_.indexOf = function(array, target){
       var result = -1;

    _.each(array, function(item, index) {
      if (item === target && result === -1) {
        result = index;
      }
    });

    return result;
  };`   this has to be a simple callback syntax mistake that i am making

Comment: @muistooshort i checked out the underscore.js source and it gave me the correct syntax `// Return all the elements that pass a truth test.
  // Delegates to **ECMAScript 5**'s native filter if available.
  // Aliased as select.
  _.filter = _.select = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    var results = [];
    if (obj == null) return results;
    if (nativeFilter && obj.filter === nativeFilter) return obj.filter(iterator, context);
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      if (iterator.call(context, value, index, list)) results.push(value);
    });
    return results;
  };`

Comment: That code would be a lot more readable inside your question than in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 _.filter = function(collection, test) {
  var result =[];
  _.each(collection, function(curio) { 
    if (test(curio)) 
    result.push(curio);
  });
  return result;
};
```

that fixed it