# access to this.var in _.filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I hava a variable `this.myvar` which is a array. I would like to make a `_.filter()` with this variable, but within the `_.filter()`-function my `this.myvar` is not known.

is there a way to solve this, or did I comepletely misunderstood something?

```
this.my_array = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'];
this.my_filter = ['aaa', 'ccc'];

my_filtered_object = _.filter(this.my_array, function(item) {           
    alert(this.my_filter.toSource());   
    /*          
    if(this.my_filter.indexOf(item) != -1) {
                return item;
    }
    */
});
```

the alert should show the values of `this.my_filter` but it seems that there is no access within `_.filter()` to that variable

Comment: can you  expose some  code

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot. I have edited the question ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586688/callback-function-with-underscore-each#answer-21592953

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous function you pass to the *_.filter()* need to be bind to your context if you want to access the *this.my_filter*.

With underscore you just need to change your code as follow:

```
my_filtered_object = _.filter(this.my_array, _.bind(function(item) {           
    alert(this.my_filter.toSource());   
    /*          
    if(this.my_filter.indexOf(item) != -1) {
                return item;
    }
    */
}, this));
```

As you can see I added the *_.bind()* method that attach the context you need to the anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

There are various solutions.

1. Store a reference in a separate variable:

   ```
   var my_filter = this.my_filter;
   my_filtered_object = _.filter(this.my_array, function(item) {           
     alert(my_filter.toSource());   
   });
   ```
2. Set the context (`this`) inside `_.filter()` to point to the `this` outside the function:

   ```
   my_filtered_object = _.filter(this.my_array, function(item) {           
     alert(this.my_filter.toSource());   
   }, this);
   ```
3. Use an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (although this might not work in every browser):

   ```
   my_filtered_object = _.filter(this.my_array, item => {
     alert(this.my_filter.toSource());
   });
   ```
4. Use [`_.bind()`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind), as suggested by Mario in his answer.

Solution #2 makes most sense to me.